# PHP Laravel Two Forms sharing a Variable

Tags: php, laravel

Currently, after images are loaded onto the page, if the user deletes an image the page is refreshed and if they end up deleting all images then an error will appear on the screen saying that the $count variable is undefined. How can this be if the page is refreshed? I know that the form at the bottom needs to have the count variable but currently, that variable is coming from inside the first form so I can't put the form in the other.

What should I do?

```
   {!! Form::open()  !!}
       ... Rest of form inputs  
       @if (count($project->getImages()) > 0)     
       @foreach ( $project->getImages() as $count => $asset)
           <div class="delete-toggle-container">
               <a href="#" data-form-submit="image-delete-{{ $count }}" class="text-danger image-delete-toggle" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete This Image"><i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
            </div>
       @endforeach
       @endif
   {!! Form::close() !!}

   {!! Form::open(['url' => '/route/resource/' . $project->id . '/images', 'method' => 'DELETE', 'id' => 'image-delete-' . $count]) !!}
   {!! Form::hidden('image', $asset, ['readonly' => true] ) !!}
   {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Comment: What should be the value of `$count` if there are no images?

Comment: I'm guessing 0 then

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could define `$count` if there are no images:

```
@if (count($project->getImages()) > 0)     
    @foreach ( $project->getImages() as $count => $asset)
        // Some content here
    @endforeach
@else
    <?php $count = 0; ?>
@endif
```

It's not the prettiest but it might work.

Comment: As great as that is I still get the same issue with the undefined $count variable on the Form open tag in the bottom form. I even tried doing $count ?: 0 but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should not be relying on a variable that is set via a `foreach` loop to exist outside of the loop. If the loop doesn't run, there is nothing to iterator over, then that variable won't be set.

Also that is a loop, do you always want the last 'key' from what was iterated as the value you need to open that form? Is that the intent or are you trying to just get an actual count to use?

Side Note, to replace the `if` then `foreach` on the same value ...:

```
@forelse (...)
    iterating
@empty
    nothing to iterate
@endforelse
```

If you are inside a loop you have the `$loop` variable available to get current index, iteration, etc ...

[Laravel - Docs - Blade - Loops](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#loops)

[Laravel - Docs - Blade - The Loop Variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#the-loop-variable)